# Insert with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have an INSERT here with PDO. It doesn't seem to work...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO client_cards 
        SET cc_num = ?,     
        cc_cvv = ?, 
        cc_month = ?, 
        cc_year = ?,
        cfname = ?,
        clname = ?,
        caddress = ?,
        ccity = ?,
        cstate = ?,
        ccountry = '212',
        czip = ?,
        `default` = ? , 
        client_id = ?";

  $query = $db->prepare($sql);
  $array = array($enc_cc_num, $enc_cc_ccv, $exp_month, $exp_year, $fname, $lname, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $set_default, $client_id);
  $query->execute(array($array));
```

Does PDO only work with INSERT INTO table (key, key, key) **VALUES**($value, $value, $value),
 but not with INSERT INTO table **SET** key = $value??

Comment: `SET` in conjunction with `INSERT`? Weird. o_O

Comment: You double wrap your variables into a twodimensional array

Comment: Does anyone else find it terrifying that someone who is *clearly storing credit card information* in their database is asking such a noob question?

Comment: @jonathon Yep, it sure is terrifying. We all start somewhere :-).

Comment: I agree - there's nothing inherently wrong with being a noob... as long as it doesn't affect the financial well-being of other persons.

Comment: @jonathon true. I'm trying to be super-careful. That's why this forum is here - no? (BTW If you really want to wet your pants... I was asked to update this site - it was using all mysql_* functions and with no real_escape_string!  :-{ )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to feed the `execute()` method an array of values. Instead you give it only one value; an array:

```
$array = array($enc_cc_num, $enc_cc_ccv, $exp_month, $exp_year, $fname, $lname, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $set_default, $client_id);
  $query->execute(array($array));
```

You need only:

```
$array = array($enc_cc_num, $enc_cc_ccv, $exp_month, $exp_year, $fname, $lname, $address, $city, $state, $zip, $set_default, $client_id);
  $query->execute($array);
                  ^^^^^^ here
```

When you open your database connection, you should tell PDO to throw exceptions when something goes wrong so that you can easily catch these mistakes.

For example:

```
    $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opt);
```

Comment: *you should tell PDO to throw exceptions* And don't forget to tell your dog or cat to catch them if they fly out of the computer ;)

Comment: @Rizier123 Interesting option, I've never tried it like that ;-)

Comment: @Ben By the way, if you don't catch your exceptions, php will show you the complete exception and stack trace by default.

Comment: @jeroen Thanks, works a treat. Thing is, I'm working on someone else's code so the error will not be displayed on the screen- where would I see the exception thrown? In the console?

Comment: @Ben If it does not show, you should be able to find it in the web-server error log. Or you catch it right there and simply do a dump of the exception object, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake we have here is syntax of insert query as SET is used in UPDATE query not in INSERT, our query will be like this :
INSERT INTO

Prepared statements basically work like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN ) VALUES ( value1, value2,...valueN );
```

- Prepare: An SQL statement template is created and sent to the database. Certain values are left unspecified, called parameters (labeled "?"). Example: INSERT INTO MyGuests VALUES(?, ?, ?)
- We need to bind values to query then the database parses, compiles, and performs query optimization on the SQL statement template, and stores the result without executing it
- Execute: At a later time, the application binds the values to the parameters, and the database executes the statement. The application may execute the statement as many times as it wants with different values

We can get some basic tutorilas over here as well http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp